# error on browsing to homepage of public sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: error, forms-authentication

I have created a public SharePoint 2010 site called http://xyz.com and when I browse to it I see the following;

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Wed, 18 May 2011 16:42:23 GMT
Connection: close

I have set up a site for forms authentication at http://xyz.com/marketing and when I browse to this URL I see the forms auth login page.

Why do I get this error above?

Comment: Are you set up with Server Roles for the Administrator with options like dbcreator, public, securityadmin or sysadmin?

Comment: Do you have a site collection at that top level?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing a site collie tion at the root of the site. Verify by viewing all sites from Central Admin and see if it lists a site at '/'